# Override the authToken views in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I am using the token based Authentication in Django and need to add User object in addition to token being returned.

How do I override this class view ? Where do I need add this class and make the changes ? Currently this is found in the rest_framework package and I don't want to modify the library .

```
from rest_framework import parsers, renderers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    print "dasdsa"

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key})


obtain_auth_token = ObtainAuthToken.as_view()
```

Answer (score 10):

From [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens).

First that you need is to extend the `ObtainAuthToken` class.

```
# views.py

from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                       context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

And after this add the `CustomAuthToken` class to your `urls.py` like `view`

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns += [
    path(r'api-token-auth/', views.CustomAuthToken.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Any idea how you could you apply a throttle to this?

Answer (score 4):

You should extend your `CustomClass` from `AuthToken`, the route default url to your `CustomClass`:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken

class JSONWebTokenAPIOverride(ObtainJSONWebToken):
    """
    Override JWT
    """
    def post(self, request):
        # Do whatever you want
```

Then in your `urls.py`:

```
url(
    r'^api-auth$',
    cache_page(0)(views.JSONWebTokenAPIOverride.as_view())
)
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to override some default CRSF functionality and used the following approach:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class SessionCsrfExemptAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        # Do not perform a csrf check
        return False
```

Then in my settings file I referenced it in the following way:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'myapp.utils.authenticate.SessionCsrfExemptAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
),
```

This allowed me to import the existing functionality, override it and reference it in the settings file. I think you can use a similar approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I use the option [JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#extending-jsonwebtokenauthentication).
In the response I include the **token**, **expiration timestamp** and the **user**.

In **settings.py** add:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
        ...
        'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':'<app_name>.functions.custom_jwt_response',
}
```

Then in **functions.py** add the following

```
def custom_jwt_response(token, user=None, request=None):

    import jwt
    jwt = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)

    return {
        'token': token,
        'token_exp': jwt['exp'],
        'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are good but in my opinion they don't make full use of inheritance. When we inherit a class, we shouldn't just try to reinvent the wheel and instead make use of the super() keyword. Here is my code example, where I want to turn the username argument into lowercase before performing the authentication request:

```
class GetAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
   """
   Override Django's ObtainAuthToken to provide custom way of authenticating user for token
   """
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      #-- turn username to lowercase
      if ('username' in request.data):
         request.data['username'] = request.data['username'].lower()

      #-- perform normal function
      return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```