# how to get the default user details (username, email, first_name, last_name) along with token (in created login API) via Django Rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the user details (username, email, first_name, last_name) along with token via API, but just getting token,

I am a beginner in Django REST framework, Please help me regarding this,

here is my code.

***settings.py***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'rest_framework',
   'knox',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
       'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
   ],
}
```

***views.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView

class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user,)[enter image description here][1]
        return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)
```

***urls.py***

```
from knox import views as knox_views
from .views import LoginAPI
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
   path('api/login/', LoginAPI.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

***http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/***

```
{
   "username": "admin123",
   "password": "Password@123"
}
```

***and response is***

```
{
   "expiry": "2020-07-30T13:34:14.041631Z",
   "token": "f4767171f1017d2bd772fd3bae43489659e8e63649361845bedc5ebabff09c15"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create your own serializer class sooner or later as it seems like the TokenSerializer class only returns the token. Something like:

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data, context={'request': request}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email,
            # and so on...
        })
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781858/12467282)