# how to get token along with user name in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-authentication

I am getting Token with I use auth API in django when I use API like
I create my username and password using createsuperuser in django

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/           [POST METHOD]
```

Token

```
{
    "token": "5f8ceaaaeef845bef8474e28192a174d3214124"
}
```

I want my token response like

```
{
    "username":"Gem",
    "token": "5f8ceaaaeef845bef8474e28192a174d3214124"
}
```

How to get like that?

My Views.py code

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'id', 'username', 'password'}
        extra_kwargs = { 'password':{'write_only': True, 'required': True} }
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from backendPractices.models import Enquiry, EnquiryUtil
from backendPractices.serialize import Users
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
import json

@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    message = "clock in server "
    return Response (data = message + date, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

class Crud(APIView):
    # get all
    def get(self, request):
        UsersData = Enquiry.objects.all().order_by('dateBooked')
        Obj = Users(UsersData, many=True)
        responsedata = Obj.data
        return Response(responsedata)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from backendPractices.models import Enquiry
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'id', 'username', 'password'}
        extra_kwargs = { 'password':{'write_only': True, 'required': True} }


class Users(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Enquiry
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Could you show view code? @Gem

Comment: to archive a username & you may need to use a [mixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins)

Comment: Sure @paras-chauhan

Comment: Added my code @paraschauhan

Comment: Mixin for token ? @AshishSondagar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override the authToken views in Django Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266636/override-the-authtoken-views-in-django-rest)